# BigQuery problem - only first row of unnest query displaying

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to understand and learn to query... but when it seems like the results are not repeating from the tutorial - it gets hard...  Can you tell me what am I not seeing?

There is an example [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays)

```
WITH races AS (
  SELECT "800M" AS race,
    [STRUCT("Rudisha" as name, [23.4, 26.3, 26.4, 26.1] as splits),
     STRUCT("Makhloufi" as name, [24.5, 25.4, 26.6, 26.1] as splits),
     STRUCT("Murphy" as name, [23.9, 26.0, 27.0, 26.0] as splits),
     STRUCT("Bosse" as name, [23.6, 26.2, 26.5, 27.1] as splits),
     STRUCT("Rotich" as name, [24.7, 25.6, 26.9, 26.4] as splits),
     STRUCT("Lewandowski" as name, [25.0, 25.7, 26.3, 27.2] as splits),
     STRUCT("Kipketer" as name, [23.2, 26.1, 27.3, 29.4] as splits),
     STRUCT("Berian" as name, [23.7, 26.1, 27.0, 29.3] as splits)]
       AS participants)
SELECT
  race,
  participant
FROM races r
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(r.participants) as a participant;

+------+---------------------------------------+
| race | participant                           |
+------+---------------------------------------+
| 800M | {Rudisha, [23.4, 26.3, 26.4, 26.1]}   |
| 800M | {Makhloufi, [24.5, 25.4, 26.6, 26.1]} |
| 800M | {Murphy, [23.9, 26, 27, 26]}          |
| 800M | {Bosse, [23.6, 26.2, 26.5, 27.1]}     |
| 800M | {Rotich, [24.7, 25.6, 26.9, 26.4]}    |
| 800M | {Lewandowski, [25, 25.7, 26.3, 27.2]} |
| 800M | {Kipketer, [23.2, 26.1, 27.3, 29.4]}  |
| 800M | {Berian, [23.7, 26.1, 27, 29.3]}      |
+------+---------------------------------------+
```

I run it in BigQuery console and get only

```
Row race    participant.name    participant.splits  
1   
    800M
              Rudisha
                                23.4
                                26.3
                                 26.4
                                26.1
```

which looks like just the first item of what should be there.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery shows rows per page in small windows.   On the bottom of the window are settings for how many rows per page to display... Json included all results and after changing the settings they could all be previewed in a standard table.

I missed that originally.